# MS Word - if value “red” appears after value “1” and before value “2” then 1 in an Excel cell

Tags: excel, ms-word

I have filled in questionnaires from a study. Correct answers can usually be identified by one word such as "red" or "car".

An idea to automate going through the answers might not be possible but I am interested in asking. Could you create a forumla or macro which adds a 1 to an excel cell (1 for correct) if between 1 and 2 (i.e., 1 for the first question and 2 for the second question) there is a certain text such as "red".

I have 67 questionnaires and if I could automate whether their answers are correct this would be really useful. As I said in other posts recently, I discovered not long ago how efficient it is to learn programming for research work that I am doing or almost any work for that matter.

Comment: Please give us a sample of how your spreadsheet is looking to understand better

Comment: Sorry for not doing this before rebrec - didn't have enough "user points" (not sure of the right term) but now I do I realised so I put a picture up now. Thanks for reminding me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what your survey output looks like, I took a stab at this. I set up a spreadsheet like below:

```
Response            1       2       3       End      Question   Answer
1red2car3catEnd     1.00    1.00    1.00    3.00        1         red
1blue2car3catEnd    0.00    1.00    1.00    2.00        2         car
1red2boat3catEnd    1.00    0.00    1.00    2.00        3         cat
1blue2boat3catEnd   0.00    0.00    1.00    1.00
```

Where Response is in A1 and Question in G1 and Answer in H1.

I used this formula in B2:

```
=IF(RIGHT(LEFT($A2,FIND(C$1,$A2)-1),(FIND(C$1,$A2)-1-FIND(B$1,$A2)))=$H$2,1,0)
```

It gets the value after the column header value but before the next column header value from the response column and compares it to the answer key on the right.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer Wyatt. It seems that using Word is not possible to automate the command I want to automate which I understand by the fact that no one else replied about how World would be used! However, I'm impressed by your attempt to create an Excel spreadsheet to try explain how one would solve my problem in Excel so even you answer relates to Excel rather than Word I admire the effort you put in and hence why I selected your answer. Also this might be useful for people in the future who will check this post because you solve my problem just in Excel. Thanks again :)

Comment: You could potentially use this solution if you copied all of the text from the questionnaires into each cell in column A and put the whole question in each column in row 1.